# Python | Load excel file in blocks(one block is separated from other by blank line) using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet and this sheet contains different sections example provided below. I want to read each section in a new data frame. For below mentioned sheet I want 3 dataframes one for each section.
What are the possible ways to read the file like this?

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4
 A1       A2     A3       A4      - Section 1
 A5       A6     A7       A8
 A9       A10    A11      A12
 na       na      na      na   (Blank line)
 B1       B2     B3       B4  - Section 2
 B5       B6     B7       B8
 na       na     na       na (Blank Line)
 C1       C2     C3       C4 - Section 3
 C5       C6     C7       C8
 C9       C10    C11      C12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a combination of pandas and numpy

```
#split the df to get blank rows
blanks=df[df.isnull().all(1)]

#split the dataframe using the index
df_list = np.split(df,blanks.index)

#drop the first row with all nan
for dfs in df_list:
    dfs=dfs.dropna(how="all",axis=0)
    print(dfs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading the full DF and then splitting it like this:

```
# creating list of indexes for separation rows
sep_rows = df[df.isnull()].index.tolist()
# splitting according to the list
sep_rows2 = [0] + sep_rows + [max(sep_rows)+1]
dfs = [df.iloc[sep_rows2[n]:sep_rows2[n+1]] for n in range(len(sep_rows2)-1)]
# Show new dfs
print (dfs[0])
print (dfs[1])
print (dfs[2])
```